# Can i change type of value of firebase data

Tags: python-3.x

I read data from firebase and It type is instance

R1T = db.child("io_relay").child("1").child("time").get()

Can i change R1T to float

Comment: Provide R1T's type or a whole code

Comment: I don't know they type ,but when i print R1T they show the number from firebase ex 425 525 and i want to change type into float and use for provide delay time , when i use type(R1T) they show <type 'instance'>

Comment: I work on rasp pi3

Comment: Could you provide an example code then I try to deal with it

Comment: R1 = db.child("io_relay").child("1").child("fan1status").get()
R1T = float(int(db.child("io_relay").child("1").child("time").get()))

if R1.val() == true:
   GPIO.output(RELAY_1, ON)
   time.sleep (R1T)
   GPIO.output(RELAY_1,OFF)
elif R1.val() == false:
   GPIO.output(RELAY_1,OFF)

it did't work and show this message 
AttributeError: PyreResponse instance has no attribute '__trunc__'

Comment: Type() built-function can show a object's type. Just type(R1T). it would be best if you give an example that it can directly run

Comment: they show <type 'instance'>